# How to interpret chi2 p-value?

Tags: chi-squared-test

I performed a haplotype analysis for two SNPs in case/control study by web-based SHEsisPlus platform. For one the haplotype, the result was Chi2=54.898, p=1.27e-13. How to interpret this p-value?

Answer (score 1):

The test was about testing haplotype distribution between your case and control samples. You should have got a table of your haplotype, and chi-square p-values for each of those.

Your test was highly significant, the distribution was different from case and normal. This is positive, because now you have something to narrow down your analysis. The point of providing control samples was to filter down uninteresting SNPs.